# Returning a function object from a function C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef, return-type, function-declaration

let the following function:

```
returntype Foo(void(*bar)(const C&));
```

what should be inserted instead of 'returntype' in order for Foo returning the passed
function\functor aka 'bar'

Comment: `decltype(bar)` might do it

Answer (score 2):

##### Method 1

One option with C++11 is to use placeholder type `auto` in the return type with `decltype` using the trailing return type syntax as shown below:

```
auto Foo(void(*bar)(const C&)) -> decltype(bar); //this is more readable than method 2 below
```

##### Method 2

```
void (*Foo(void(*bar)(const C&)))(const C&); //less readable than method 1 above
```

As we can see, method 1 is *more readable* than method 2.

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach is the following

```
void ( *Foo(void(*bar)(const C&)) ( const C & );
```

Or you could use a using or typedef alias like

```
using Fp = void ( * )( const C & );

or 

typedef void ( *Fp )( const C & );
```

and after that

```
Fp Foo( Fp bar );
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function `void bar(const C&)`, and consider `Foo(bar)`.

In order to call the returned function pointer, you need to dereference it first, `(*Foo(bar))`, and then pass it a `const C&` (let's call it "the_c"):

```
(*Foo(bar))(the_c)
```

Since `fn` returns `void`, you can now fill in the types:

```
    void (*Foo(void(*bar)(const C&)))(const C&)
      ^        ^                  ^      ^
      |        |<-  parameter   ->|      | parameter for the returned function       
      |
 Ultimate result
```

Or, you could decide to not give up on your sanity yet, and name the type:

```
using function = void(*)(const C&);
function Foo(function bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with a templates function:

```
template<typename F>
F foo(F func)
{
//logic
 return func

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).